# MacBook Air not contacting Wi-Fi with NETGEAR Extender

Tags: network, wifi, airport

My MacBook Air is not connecting to Wi-Fi through NETGEAR Extender whilst all other device do, such as MacBook Pro, Apple TV and iPad.

I tried to:

- Delete all Network configurations from System Preferences.
- Reset SMC.
- Reset PRAM.
- Change channel on NETGEAR to channel 48.
- Disable password access on NETGEAR.

MacBook Air OSX 10.8.5
13 inches
Ending 2010

Any help please?

Comment: Do you have your router set up to use MAC filtering by chance?

Comment: Other devices work fine such as a MacBook Pro, iPad, Apple TV, and other devices.

Answer (score 1):

Change the authentication method from WPA2 Personal to WPA or WEP. If the Air is older it may not be compatible.

Comment: I will try… although I even tried to set the connection without password at all ...and all devices work fine whilst the Mac Book Air does not!!!

Comment: You just have to work through all the possibilities.  If everything else is eliminated then it would point to the Airport card.  But if the Macbook Air works on other networks there would be no point changing this.